# Can too much space between valves and camshaft cause oil in cylinder?

Tags: toyota, valve, tacoma, oil-consumption

My 2006 Toyota Tacoma v6 is losing profuse amounts of oil although it runs just fine after adding more. I did a comprehensive overhaul several years ago and tuned the valves (ground them and readjusted tapets AKA lifters) but I just lifted the valve cover and redid the feeler gauge test and one (out of 4) tapets on one cylinder has too much spacing between it and the camshaft. The same cylinder (I believe) also fails the cylinder leak down test, the pressure inside the cylinder being lower than the compressor.

Could too much spacing between the camshaft and one of the tapets cause oil to get inside the cylinder from the camshaft chamber under the valve cover?

Comment: My thinking is, No. There really isn't a correlation between the two. The only way oil can get into the cylinder from the head side is past the valve seals. It really doesn't care how much clearance there is between the cam and lifter.

Comment: How do you know the oil is coming from the top end?  It could also be past the piston rings, through a break in the head gasket, or via a crack in the block or head.

Comment: @jwh20 because it started happening right after my tuneup and I didn't touch the engine block including the pistons and rings.

Comment: @jwh20 but I don't really know, just asking

Comment: My thinking is it could be related to the bad valve, but nothing to do with the clearance. It COULD be the clearance is due to something below it.

Comment: Did you replace the valve seals when you did this valve tuning work?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, I bought a complete set of gaskets, including the head as well as valve seals

Comment: Did you check the valves stems for wear? Scoring, ovality etc?

Comment: @SolarMike they all looked good

Comment: There can be a world of difference between “looked good” and “are good”. Have you checked the exhaust emissions - that may tell you about what extra is turning up.

Comment: @SolarMike I have not, is there a way to do that DIY?

Comment: The condition of the spark plugs should give you an indication of why cylinder is burning oil, if that is what is happening.  If one looks black and sooty or oily, you know which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Do the exhaust gasses look like oil is being burnt?

Comment: @HandyHowie the exhaust looks good and the plugs are sooty but not oily but I think it's from a different issue I'm currently working on